# C Simple Logging Management

Tags: c, logging, syslog, log4c

I'm currently using the not so sophisticated `printf` method of logging; and I'm wondering whether to use something like "`log4c`" "`zlog`" or "`syslog`" to better manage ongoing debug/informational output. I'm not asking for a "best" library for the task; but for help on choosing when the added complexity and dependency of a logging library is outweighed by the neatness and organization provided. What level of complexity of a project merits a special purpose library?

Comment: I'd recommend using a library as soon as you are thinking about needing anything more sophisticated than `printf()` or `fprintf(stderr, ...)`.  It needn't necessarily be a very complex library, but having something to use that allows you compile-time and run-time controls over what diagnostics are available and appear is very useful in 'bigger' programs (for an ill-defined value of 'bigger' -- I'd suggest maybe 'more than 4 main, non-library source files').

Answer (score 0):

When debugging, use `fprintf(stderr, .... );`

When logging for long term use, suggest syslog() because:

1. the syslog contents are automatically archived each day.
2. the syslog is where most users go to help trace project activity.
3. the syslog records are date/time stamped.
4. syslog is very flexible on the data contents portion of the records.